# Name of this theorem about space dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Bit of a dumb question but I talked about this theorem in my Linear Algebra class

$dim (U + V) = dim (V) + dim (U) - dim (U \cap V)$

But I didn't understand its name... it's theorem of Gass(something) ... Does anyone have any idea what's the name of this theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $U \cap V $?

Comment: My mistake, thanks!

Comment: You may be thinking of Grassman's theorem.

Comment: Probably [Grassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann)